# Best place in project to put a file with polyfill for cross-browser JavaScript support

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, polyfills

Wondering where in a React / Redux app (created using `create-react-app`) is the optimal place to locate/place any files that will serve as custom polyfills for browsers that lack support.  Specifically, I need to be able to use `Array.prototype.includes` and `String.prototype.startsWith`, along with a few other methods that aren't supported in Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Tay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you `eject` your React/Redux app (created using `create-react-app`), 
you should find the `polyfills.js` at `/config` folder.

Then you can add your polyfill codes, or use those suggested by  Mozilla Developer Network:

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=example)

[String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

I hope above does help.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.  Thanks Dust!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) it will be installed using npm and the code will be under the `node_modules` folder.

You can import it from your application's entry point:

```
require('core-js')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ower.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `index.js` file or app entry file and you are done!

```
import 'core-js/es6/';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Add some description

Comment: add this line to your index.js file or app entry file and you are done!

`import 'core-js/es6/';`

Comment: This answer needs some more info to be useful for people not familiar with the javascript ecosystem.